# how to add a line below title in baposter

Tags: titles, posters, baposter

I am using `baposter` to prepare my poster. I am trying to put affiliations *below* the authors' names - here's my try:

```
\documentclass[landscape,paperwidth=48in,paperheight=96in,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
 boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=4em]{logo1}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{Title: \\ subtitle}\vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Name1$^{\ast,\S}$, Name2$^{\dagger}$, Name3$^{\ast}$ \& Name4$^{\ast,\S}$} \hspace{12pt} } %Authors
{\footnotesize\itshape $^{\ast}$University of Connecticut, $^{\S}$CT Institute for the Brain and Cognitive Sciences, $^{\dagger}$NYU Abu Dhabi} % <----------- Institution: how to put this below author's names?
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{logo2}} % Second university/lab logo on the right
```

which doesn't compile as wanted. Do you guys have any idea of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have the class available to me, but you could express your title with teh `stackengine` package as `\bfseries\scshape\stackunder{Title:}{subtitle}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title section syntax are: `{left image}` `{Poster title}` `{Poster authors}` `{right image}`. Thus, four items need to be specified, each enclosed in `{}`. The affiliations need to be included inside `{Poster authors}`. It is not possible to just insert a new specification `{affiliations}`, which is what the MWE tries to do.

So, writing `{authors \\ affiliations}` will get the job done. Since each of the title section contents is a node, you can construct them in any way you wish. For example, if you had two authors, each with a different affiliation you could write:

```
{ % Authors and affiliations
\begin{tabular}{ll}
author 1 & affiliation 1 \\
author 2 & affiliation 2
\end{tabular}
} % End of author and affiliations
```

This approach requires more vertical space so instead of using `headerheight=0.1\textheight` you might need, say, `headerheight=0.12\textheight`.

I didn't use that approach here, and just stayed with the format indicated by what was posted. Only a small change is required. Instead of:

```
{\textsc{Name1$^{\ast,\S}$, Name2$^{\dagger}$, Name3$^{\ast}$ \& Name4$^{\ast,\S}$} \hspace{12pt} } %Authors
{\footnotesize\itshape $^{\ast}$University of Connecticut, $^{\S}$CT Institute for the Brain and Cognitive Sciences, $^{\dagger}$NYU Abu Dhabi} % <----------- Institution: how to put this below author's names?
```

you need:

```
{\textsc{Name1$^{\ast,\S}$, Name2$^{\dagger}$, Name3$^{\ast}$ \& Name4$^{\ast,\S}$} \hspace{12pt} } %Authors
{\footnotesize\itshape $^{\ast}$University of Connecticut, $^{\S}$CT Institute for the Brain and Cognitive Sciences, $^{\dagger}$NYU Abu Dhabi} % <----------- Institution: how to put this below author's names?
```

The corrected code deletes the `}` before `%Authors` and the `{` before `\footnotesize`.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,paperwidth=48in,paperheight=96in,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
 boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bfseries\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%--------------------------------------------------------------------
{\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image-a}} % First university/lab logo on the left
%{\bf\textsc{Title: \\ subtitle}\vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title
{\bf\textsc{Title:}\vspace{0.3em}} % Poster title
%{}
{\textsc{Name1$^{\ast,\S}$, Name2$^{\dagger}$, Name3$^{\ast}$ \& Name4$^{\ast,\S}$} \hspace{12pt}  \\%Authors
\footnotesize\itshape $^{\ast}$University of Connecticut, $^{\S}$CT Institute for the Brain and Cognitive Sciences, $^{\dagger}$NYU Abu Dhabi} % <----------- Institution: how to put this below author's names?
{\includegraphics[height=4em]{example-image-a}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```